# Why does the inverse of a sound wave sound exactly like the original?

Tags: algorithm, math, audio, noise-reduction

I have an audio source (I am working on a project with another member in SO who has also been asking questions)

IN time domain, we have 44100 samples of signed 4 byte integers.  In time domain we negate each sample.

In frequency domain, as another user helped point out to us, we shifted the phase by 180 degrees by negating the real and imaginary parts of each frequency value

In both cases, the resulting audio wave sounds exactly like the original source.  Is this expected (maybe because the wave for is essentially the same, just reversed?)

Steve

Comment: Positive and negative numbers become changes in air pressure that move your eardrum to and fro - it doesn't matter which is the to and which the fro, it's the speed of change that matters.

And this question is totally off-topic, of course.

Comment: -1: I'm not sure this could be any more off-topic.

Comment: -1: Although interesting, this really doesn't belong in this forum

Comment: @Troubadour He *is* asking if this is the expected behavior for his program.  Not certain if that will sway the moderator's doubts as to whether or not this should be closed, but I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: @Tim Pote: The question boils down to physics, not programming.

Comment: Presumably the question "what is the RGB value for yellow?" is similarly off-topic. Serves people right for trying to write programs with practical applications -- the application is off-topic (whatever it may be) ;-p

Comment: This question and all the other questions on FFTs, complex numbers, noise cancellation, etc, really belong on http://DSP.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the expected behavior.  The ear detects frequency and in both cases, though the phase may have changed, the frequency is the same.

However, you can combine the original wave and the phase-shifted wave to get interesting sound cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would expect the phase shifted signal to sound exactly the same.  The point of your related question is that if you took a signal and added it to a copy that was 180 phase shifted, the result would be zero due to destructive interference.